# Can't limit scope of variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, scope, package

Can anyone get the function and class scoping feature to work, as documented in 
[Scoping Classes with Packages](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brfynt_-1.html) ?

I create a directory C:\Windows\Temp+undergrad
I put a file foo.m in there tat defines a function foo.
I make sure C:\Windows\Temp is on the matlab path
In matlab, type 'what undergrad' should result in a list of functions and classes defined in the package.  Instead I get "undergrad not found."

I am using MATLAB Version 7.4.0.287 (R2007a) student version.

Anyone have an idea if this package scoping stuff actually works in this version of Matlab?  The documentation gives no indication of what version the feature was introduced in.

Comment: New MATLAB OO (which you references) works officially starting from R2008a although some features were available (undocumented) in earlier versions

Comment: One thing to check: Did you do `clear classes` after you changed the class definition? http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/clear.html

Answer (score 1):

Packages were introduced in R2008a; your version is older than that. Unfortunately, The MathWorks do not list what versions a feature works with on that feature's documentation page.

See the release notes for R2008a: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/rn/brjk1q5-1.html#brjk1q5-4